# Why does my web page show page from previous host when not using www?

Tags: php, html, web, namecheap

I bought a domain from GoDaddy looking to set up my first webpage. I followed through some of the free trial of the GoDaddy Website Builder before buying my hosting plan at Namecheap, where I am looking to use the CPanel interface to organise my site. I have changed the nameservers for the domain to the ones for Namecheap. The problem is, when I do not include the www, I am still taken to the page set up by the GoDaddy website builder, despite having cancelled my subscription to this website builder. Anyone know what is going on?
https://theworldsbestsite.com
http://www.theworldsbestsite.com
Thanks :)

Comment: You cleared your browser cache? And/or tried with other browsers too?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "It's just a cache problem"

Comment: Thank you Rafal and Simone. New to all this and did not know that was the case. I will leave the question here in case any other rookies find a similar problem. :) have a nice day

Comment: It is your cache issue. Have you tested from different networks?